# PhantomJS selenium NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, ubuntu, selenium, phantomjs, nosuchelementexception

I have created a web crawler with Selenium (using selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar) and phantomJs (phantomjs -v returns 1.9.0 on Ubuntu 14.04). The code was working fine with both with FirefoxDriver and PhantomJSDriver on Windows 10, but only works with FirefoxDriver under Ubuntu 14.04.

Sample code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DesiredCapabilities DesireCaps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    DesireCaps.setCapability("phantomjs.binary.path", "/usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs");

    WebDriver driver=new PhantomJSDriver(DesireCaps);

    String Url = "https://xxx";
    driver.get(Url);

    WebElement rootWebElement = driver.findElement(By.id("main"));
    List<WebElement> parentElements = rootWebElement.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    //243 , 240 (previous)
    for (int i = 106; i < parentElements.size(); i++) {

        WebElement href =parentElements.get(i).findElement(By.tagName("z"));
        if(href!=null){

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(href.getAttribute("href"));
            try {
                scanner.parseXML(href.getAttribute("href"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

If you open the provided URL's source.... you can easily see that the tag with id="main" exists...

Stack Trace:

```
PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...
[INFO  - 2015-08-13T14:15:57.720Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 8677
[INFO  - 2015-08-13T14:15:58.361Z] Session [d17a3cc0-41c5-11e5-bedb-6fa39763a2c0] - CONSTRUCTOR - Desired Capabilities: {"phantomjs.binary.path":"/usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs"}
[INFO  - 2015-08-13T14:15:58.370Z] Session [d17a3cc0-41c5-11e5-bedb-6fa39763a2c0] - CONSTRUCTOR - Negotiated Capabilities: {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.0","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.0.3","platform":"linux-unknown-32bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}
[INFO  - 2015-08-13T14:15:58.371Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: d17a3cc0-41c5-11e5-bedb-6fa39763a2c0
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with id 'main''
 caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"29","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:8677","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.7.0_79)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"id\",\"value\":\"main\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/d17a3cc0-41c5-11e5-bedb-6fa39763a2c0/element"}
Command duration or timeout: 281 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'Vmbox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=main}
Session ID: d17a3cc0-41c5-11e5-bedb-6fa39763a2c0
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=phantomjs, rotatable=false, driverVersion=1.0.3, locationContextEnabled=false, version=1.9.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=false, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={proxyType=direct}, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=false, driverName=ghostdriver, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:389)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:215)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
    at LinkScanner.main(LinkScanner.java:27)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ScreenshotException: Screen shot has been taken
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'Vmbox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:138)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with id 'main''
 caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"29","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:8677","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.4.1 (Java/1.7.0_79)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"id\",\"value\":\"main\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/d17a3cc0-41c5-11e5-bedb-6fa39763a2c0/element"}
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'Vmbox', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post my comment as answer :)
You need to install PhantomJS 1.9.8 from https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads